# Copy results of strtok to 2 strings in C

Tags: c, strtok, strcpy

Ok, so I have the code

```
char *token;
char *delimiter = " ";

token = strtok(command, delimiter);

strcpy(command, token);

token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
strcpy(arguments, token);
```

and it gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS when i run it, and yes, command and arguments are already defined.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/2523467

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you copying the token into `command` when you're parsing `command`? It's a very unsafe thing to do.

You can do:

```
char *command_tok, *args_tok;

command_tok = strtok(command, delimiter);
args_tok = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
```

Now `command_tok` and `args_tok` point to the command and arguments part of the initial string, assuming it parses correctly. Note that they point to parts of the `command` buffer and don't have their own allocated memory. You can safely copy from them into other buffers.