# How do you split a string in C?

Tags: c, string, algorithm

If I have a string like:

```
const char* mystr = "Test Test Bla Bla \n Bla Bla Test \n Test Test \n";
```

How would I use the newline character '\n', to split the string into an array of strings?

I'm trying to accomplish in C,  the thing `string.Split()` does in C# or boost's string algorithm `split` does in C++ .

Comment: C# or C? The title of your question asks for a C solution but your answer implies (bar the grammatical error) that you need a C# solution. Strtok() C and C# has String.split()

Comment: @DarkStar1 C, sorry for the mistake, I was typing in a hurry. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string to 2 strings in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523467/how-to-split-a-string-to-2-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use the `strtok` function. Be aware that it modifies the source memory so you can't use it with a string literal.

```
char *copy = strdup(mystr);
char *tok;

tok = strtok(copy, "\n");
/* Do something with tok. */
while (tok) {
    tok = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    /* ... */
}

free(copy);
```

Comment: @IntermediateHacker Added. Didn't test it, feel free to point out errors.

Comment: Manual and example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)

Comment: @user411313 But it can be easily implemented using `malloc` and `strcpy`.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to split a string in C is to use `strtok()` however that comes along with an arm's length list of caveats on its usage:

1. It's destructive (destroys the input string), and you couldn't use it on the string you have above.
2. It's not reentrant (it keeps its state between calls, and you can only be using it to tokenize one string at a time... let alone if you wanted to use it with threads). Some systems provide a reentrant version, e.g. `strtok_r()`. Your example might be split up like:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>

   int main (void) {
     char mystr[] = "Test Test Bla Bla \n Bla Bla Test \n Test Test \n";
     char *word = strtok(mystr, " \n");

      while (word) {
         printf("word: %s\n", word);
         word = strtok(NULL, " \n");
      }

      return 0;
   }
   ```

Note the important change of your string declaration -- it's now an array and can be modified. It's possible to tokenize a string without destroying it, of course, but C does not provide a simple solution for doing so as part of the standard library.

Comment: FYI, you have to indent a code example *eight* spaces if it's inside a list.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! My mind kind of melted for a second at why it didn't work so I through in an hline :).

Answer (score 1):

Remember that C makes you do all the memory allocation by hand.  Remember also that C doesn't really have *strings*, only arrays of characters.  Also, string literals are immutable, so you're going to need to copy it.  It will be easier to copy the whole thing first.

So, something like this (wholly untested):

```
char *copy = xstrdup(mystr);
char *p;
char **arry;
size_t count = 0;
size_t i;

for (p = copy; *p; p++)
  if (*p == '\n')
    count++;

arry = xmalloc((count + 1) * sizeof(char *));

i = 0;
p = copy;
arry[i] = p;
while (*p)
{
  if (*p == '\n')
  {
    *p = '\0';
    arry[i++] = p+1;
  }
  p++;
}

return arry; /* deallocating arry and arry[0] is 
                the responsibility of the caller */
```

Answer (score 1):

In the above reactions, I see only while(){} loops, where IMHO for(){} loops are more compact.

cnicutar:

```
for(tok = strtok(copy, "\n");tok; tok = strtok(NULL, "\n") {
    /* ... */
}
```

FatalError:

```
char *word;
for ( word = strtok(mystr, " \n");word; word = strtok(NULL, " \n") {
   printf("word: %s\n", word);
}
```

Zack:

```
for (arry[i=0]=p=copy; *p ; p++)
{
  if (*p == '\n')
  {
    *p = '\0';
    arry[i++] = p+1;
  }
}
```

[the clarity of this last example is disputable]

Comment: I used a while loop specifically because I think for loops are harder to read when you need to initialize a whole bunch of variables.  I mean, dude, you put a variable initialization *inside an array index*.

Comment: That is indeed questionable. But having all of the loop machinery concentrated inside the for() line is far more readable than having scattered p++ or i++ at the end of the loop body, IMHO.

Answer (score -2):

You can use below mentioned library. It has many other useful functions.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html

Or you can use strtok function.