# Read name value pairs from a file in C

Tags: c, file

I want to open a .txt file in C and read the name value pairs in the .txt file and each value in a different variable. The txt file has only 3 lines.

```
Name1 =  Value1
Name2 =  Value2
Name3 =  Value3
```

I want to extract the values corresponding to name 1, 2 and 3 and store them in a variable. How do I go about it?

Comment: I edited to what I think you wanted the format to be, but I'm not sure. Basically I removed the fluff.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2523494/544198)

```
#include <string.h>

char *token;

char *search = "=";

 static const char filename[] = "file.txt";
FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );
if ( file != NULL )
{
  char line [ 128 ]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
  while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) /* read a line */
  {
    // Token will point to the part before the =.
    token = strtok(line, search);
    // Token will point to the part after the =.
    token = strtok(NULL, search);
  }
  fclose ( file );
}
```

I'll leave the rest for you to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can read file line by line using fgets function. Gives every line in a string.
Then use strtok function to Split string into tokens using space as a delimiter.
So you will get Value1,Value2...

Answer (score 0):

Create a pointer for the file.

```
FILE *fp;
char line[3];
```

Open the file.

```
fp = fopen(file,"r");
if (fp == NULL){
  fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file %s!\n", file);
  exit(1);  
}
```

Read content line by line.

```
for (count = 0; count < 3; count++){      
   if (fgets(line,sizeof(line),fp)==NULL)
      break;
   else {               

      //do things with line variable

      name = strtok(line, '=');
      value = strtok(NULL, '=');



  }  
}
```

Don't forget to close the file!

```
fclose(fp);
```