# Reading text files into an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, text

Just got a question regards, when you read lines of text from a text file how would you separate the words and store them into an array.

For example if I have two lines of text in my text file that looks like this:

1005; AndyCool; Andy; Anderson; 23; LA
1006; JohnCool; John; Anderson; 23; LA

How would you split them into based on the ';' .
And then store them in  2D array.

Sorry I haven't started my coding just yet to paste it here

Cheers ...

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523467/how-to-split-a-string-to-2-strings-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `strsep` function:

```
char* token;
char* line;

/* I assume the line as loaded from file  */;

if( line != NULL ) {
  while ((token = strsep(&line, ";")) != NULL)
  {
     /* 
         token points to the current extracted string, 
         use it to fill your array 
      */
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First read using fgets, then use strtok to split a string http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the manual pages for fopen, fgets, strstr and  and strchr and strspn functions ... The strtok and strsep functions also work for most things you will do.