# How to use strtok() to split the given string containing spaces into multiple strings?

Tags: c, split, strtok

I have a file named email.txt, which contains some text. I am trying to split the given string containing spaces into multiple strings. The program I wrote does not split the words into separate lines. It gives me the output of the last word of the file.
Here is my code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXCHAR 1000
int main()
{
    FILE *fp2;    
    char str2[MAXCHAR];
    int line = 0;
    char delim[] = " ";
    int init_size = strlen(str2);
    fp2 = fopen("email.txt","r");
    while( fgets( str2, MAXCHAR, fp2 )) {
        line++;
        // printf(" %s",str2);  
    }
    char *ptr = strtok(str2, delim);
    
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }       
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the domain names are separated by spaces you can use `fscanf(fp2, "%s", str2)`

Comment: "The program I wrote is not giving me the desired output. It's not working." This is not a useful problem description. What does it output instead? What input do you provide? What output do you expect for that sample input?

Comment: You can find solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523467/how-to-split-a-string-to-2-strings-in-c

Comment: You do `strlen(str2)` while `str2` is still uninitialized. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You can use a *String Literal* for `delim`, e.g. `const char *delim = " ";`, but you may also want to add `'\t'` and `'\n'` so if the delimiter is a `tab` your parsing still works and `'\n'` to ensure you trim the `'\n'` from the last domain, e.g. `const char *delim = " \t\n";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **first** looping over all the lines in your file, and **then** you loop over `strtok()` returns. This means you only ever tokenize the **last** line read.

You need to nest those loops -- read a line, tokenize, then read the next line.

```
while( fgets( str2, MAXCHAR, fp2 )) {
    char * ptr;
    line++;
    //  printf(" %s",str2);
    ptr = strtok(str2, delim);

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate over all the characters and then output either

- the character you just read or
- if the character is a space, a newline character